In MAUI, how to load the colors in ./Styles/Colors.xaml from within ./Platforms/Windows/App.xaml + App.xaml.cs?
In ./Styles/Colors.xaml I have a bunch of colors like this:
<Color x:Key="IIT_Purple">#6A00FF</Color>


Which I can reference in my "any-platform" XAML code without any problems, using Background="{StaticResource IIT_Purple}".
However when I try to do the same in ./Platforms/Windows/App.xaml the program hits a break with an unhandled runtime exception:

(Click to enlarge)
If I copy the <Color>'s from ./Styles/Colors.xaml in to ./Platforms/Windows/App.xaml then they work perfectly - but this goes against the DRY/WET principle since it is duplicating the code.

Similarly in ./Platforms/Windows/App.xaml.cs I have had to duplicate the colors again, like so:
var IIT_Purple = Color.FromArgb("#6A00FF").ToWindowsColor();


How can I reference the colors that are in ./Styles/Colors.xaml from within the WinUI platform-specific code please?
Both in ./Platforms/Windows/App.xaml as well as ./Platforms/Windows/App.xaml.cs.

I success to override the colors in App.xaml by Resources["IIT_Purple"] = Microsoft.UI.Colors.White; , I have also tried by Temp_ResourceDictionary.Add("IIT_Purple", FromMyColors); Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Temp_ResourceDictionary); , however, none of them  updated the UI with the new color,I think because the UI is rendered once, or before override color take place, or StaticResource not DynamicResource, I hope this information is helpful, Good Luck!

You can get it through Resources from your MAUI Application class,
var Color= Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.Resources.GetResource<Color>("IIT_Purple");

Oh yeah GetResource is an Extension I created a while back
public static T GetResource<T>(this ResourceDictionary dictionary, string key)
{
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value) && value is T resource)
        return resource;
    else
        return default;
}


Nice, thank you - this is perfect for getting the colors in App.xaml.cs :) Do you know how to use the colors in App.xaml at all please? Thanks a lot!

I mean I am not sure what you mean by get in App.xaml, like use it in your native windows XAML?

Yes, if I use {StaticResource IIT_Purple} from the Windows Platform XAML then it crashes with an unhandled exception, whereas it works fine from the any-platform XAML

Yeah because it will not search that way natively, if you want this you need to create a property that accesses this color from the cross-platform code and then use that property statically or as a binding. Native Windows platform does not know MAUI classes exist and hence can never support what you are expecting, this is undoable unless you decide to create copies
